# function rest parameters throw error

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, parameters

running:

```
$> node restparamstest.js
```

where:

`restparamstest.js`

```
var addTestNotification = function(x, ...theArgs) {
theArgs.forEach(function (post) {
    console.log(post);
});
};
addTestNotification(1, 2, 4);
```

throws:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { var addTestNotification = function(x, ...theArgs) {
                                                                                                    ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:968:3
```

on node version:

```
console.log(process.versions);
{ http_parser: '2.5.2',
  node: '4.4.7',
  v8: '4.5.103.36',
```

any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rest parameters are fully supported only since node 6.31. If you want to use them with earlier versions of node, you should use the `--harmony` flag.

You can see ES2015 support by node version [here](http://node.green/).

Answer (score 2):

Give it a try like this

```
node --harmony restparamstest.js
```